# Device Not Registered error on Samsung Tablet when no internet connectivity

Tags: codenameone

I get the following error:

> "Device Not Registered: Sending a log from the unregistered device is impossible" even with pro account.

Tablet uses both Wifi and Carrier network for internet. This will not occur when the phone is connected to the internet. It only displays when device disconnected from the internet. After a minute I then receive a message - "App has stopped. Restart app." Please advise if any one encounter similar issue. This is not observed in IOS.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In order to send the log we need to ID the device/developer. If there is no internet connection we can't do that.

We try to fallback to register on the fly but if the register failed then you can't proceed to sending. This error means there is still no valid internet connection at this time. You can check that through `Log.getDeviceId() != -1` in the current version but it will stop working next week and always return -1;

Next week we'll have `Log.getDeviceKey() != null` which will indicate if a device successfully registered and can send a log.

Comment: Thanks for the info Shai. But there should be mechanism to capture the events and send the log when it gets connected with internet right?

Comment: send log will work once you have  stable connection. Just don't invoke `sendLog()` without a connection

Comment: will    Log.bindCrashProtection(true); will also fail when there is no stable connection? Please advise.

Comment: Yes. I'll fix that.

Comment: @Shai..this has been fixed yet?

Comment: Yes it's in the servers